# Powershell - print rows containing duplicate values in 3 columns

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to output a file containing only the rows that have 3 duplicate values with 3 columns.

Csv Current Example:

I only want to find duplicates on columns (2, 3, **and** 5), then output these rows to a results csv file

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6
1a,32,46,1,1111,poiu
2b,12,43,123,3333,zxcv
3c,12,36,344,5555,asdf
4d,12,36,64,5555,qwer
5e,12,36,22,8888,lkjh
6f,10,36,5432,7777,mnbv
```

The results csv file should have:

```
3c,12,36,344,5555,asdf
4d,12,36,64,5555,qwer
```

Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by those columns, filter for groups that have more than 1 entry, expand those groups, export to csv.

```
Import-CSV $File | group Column2,Column3,Column5 | Where{$_.Count -gt 1} | Select -Expand Group | Export-CSV $Output -Noheader
```